# Way to negate a number of pixels from and element with width 100%?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple search form:

```
<div class="search">
  <input placeholder="Search term here">
  <button>
    Go
  </button>
</div>
```

Naturally, the button goes to the right of the input. However, on mobile devices, I want to reverse this - to have the button on the left.

To that effect I have created:

```
.search {
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

button {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ufLoj5se/5/

But of course this pushes the button on to a 2nd line.

Is there a way to negate the 30px width of the button from the input to allow the button to sit snugly on the left?

Comment: Use [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc). Something like calc(100% - 40px) for the width of input

Comment: What do you mean by mobile devices? is it based on screen resolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of juggling around floats, you could use flex-box.

You could position your elements any where you need, more precisely depending on your screen resolution.

Here is what you could do.

```css
.search {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  order: 1;
}
button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  order: 2;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  button {
    order: 1;
  }
  input {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <input placeholder="Search term here">
  <button>
    Go
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I really appreciate you going above and beyond with demonstrating the correct way to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

use `calc()` function like this:

```
.search {
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: 30px;
}

button {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```